# Customer Address Field is Mandatory?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

A client of our IA app just reported a slew of IDS synch error messages like:

Error updating customer  in Intuit Data Services. Error message was: empty addresses not allowed party_id = 679598

I looked at your new online docs and see that the Object Reference indicates that the customer address is "mandatory". Is this something new? If so, since when? Customers have been synching successfully with empty addresses up to now, this change took us completely unaware (if indeed it is a change). Is there some way you can apprise us of upcoming changes so we can act proactively? Also, what exactly qualifies as an "empty" address? What fields exactly, at a minimum, need to be non-empty? For example, if "State" is filled in is that enough?

BTW, what is party_id and how can I use it to identify the customer object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a required field to add/update a customer but if you are including the XML address fields tag in your request, then you must enter a value for it. If you don't want to update the address then leave it out.

thanks,
Jarred

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Mod xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" RequestId="7699faaff20f4e16987e26bddbbf9461" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
   <ExternalRealmId>156234822</ExternalRealmId>
   <Object xsi:type="Customer">
   <Id>43497400</Id>
   <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
   <MetaData>
     <CreatedBy>app</CreatedBy>
     <CreatedById>1</CreatedById>
     <CreateTime>2010-06-18T03:48:36</CreateTime>
     <LastModifiedBy>app</LastModifiedBy>
     <LastModifiedById>1</LastModifiedById>
     <LastUpdatedTime>2010-06-18T03:48:36</LastUpdatedTime>
   <MetaData>
   <Synchronized>false</Synchronized>
   <PartyReferenceId>51077676</PartyReferenceId>
   <TypeOf>Person</TypeOf>
   <Name>Jane Doe</Name>
   <ShowAs>Jane</ShowAs>
   </Object>
</Mod>
```

Comment: Thanks, but let me make sure I have this correct: I can choose to omit the "Physical Address" entirely (I'm using the .NET DevKit). But IF I INCLUDE Physical Address then each string element (e.g. "Line1") can only be assigned a value if that value is not empty (i.e. "")? I appreciate the help, the admonition in the online docs that "the customer address field is mandatory" seems somewhat misleading, although I realize that's not your problem. :)